# Playing terraria on Ubuntu - Graphic card driver needed?

Tags: terraria, ubuntu, wine

I'm trying to get Terraria working on my Ubuntu notebook (Xubuntu actually).
I followed [this guide](http://tom-geiger.de/?p=163) and after hours of struggling I finally managed to install XNA, and .net and all the Microsoft stuff. But after starting the game, it crashes with an error - No suitable graphic card found. When I checked [this list](http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php?title=Graphics_card_compatibility) I saw my card (Intel GMA 945) isn't on the "not working" list, but similar cards are. But the fun part is, that there was Win XP before on that machine, and Terraria worked there.

Do I need to update the graphic driver somehow, or override the Ubuntu's default one?

If this question is more suitable for ubuntu stackexchange forum, please migrate it, I had doubts where to post it.

Comment: I doubt anyone will have a complete answer for you, since the use case is so specific, and this is probably more a Wine question than a gaming question, or even an Ubuntu question.

Comment: ooof many avoid the .NET games in Ubuntu.  At that point, virtual machine a windows box, I bet that'd be easier.

Comment: I second robb's comment. After the amount of trouble I had to go through to get terraria working with wine (manually resolving dependencies and compiling for hours on end makes me a sad Fambida), I have to recommend just using a VM. If you insist on using wine, be sure to run it from a terminal so you can get more detailed error messages for your endless googling pleasure. You might just get lucky and find out you need a package that's already in the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Cards are known for having bad OpenGL Support. And on Ubuntu, you will always use OpenGL as backend.

What you need to do is to get accelerated graphics drivers for this card for ubuntu:
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=13815&ProdId=2301&lang=eng&OSVersion=Linux*&DownloadType=

Try installing those and check with glxgears if you get acceleration.

Then Terraria might work.

No promises though.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that when I get to my Ubuntu computer again